# First time changing a faucet and i am stuck

Tags: repair, kitchens, faucet, sink

I am a complete novice in terms of changing faucets (and DIY generally), but you have to start somewhere right?

I need to change my kitchen faucet and of course I am already getting stuck with the first step. I am trying to remove the faucet cap (the red/blue, round indicator thing) but it seems stuck. I tried to remove it with a needle and a pointed, thin knife, but I only damaged the plastic in the process. See picture. [image]

The second issue is, I am not sure where I can switch off the water for this faucet. It looks unlike any description on the internet under my sink.

[image]

Really appreciate any help from you more experienced people!

Cori

Comment: Why do you want to remove that label? And it doesn't look like you're able to turn it off under the sink; it doesn't look like there's any valves. You probably have to turn it off at a earlier point, possibly the intake.

Comment: with this model you need to remove the red/blue thing in order to disassemble the faucet. There is some type of screw under it which you can only access if you take it off. You say at an earlier intake, do you mean somewhere outside the house? Any ideas where it would be?

Comment: To remove faucet you don't need to disassemble it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too much for a comment, doesn't quite answer the actual question, but contains information the OP should be aware of.*

Where the flexi-hose attaches to the solid pipe, the installer should have put small in-line shut-off valves [You should have one of these behind every tap in the house].
Either someone skimped at your expense, or they're not compulsory in your territory.

You'll have to track back to the next shut off - which, if you're really unlucky, is right at the point the water service enters the house [or even out in the street.]
If you shut off a long way from the tap, remember to open all the taps in the house so you don't get any surprises when you let air into the system by removing your tap unit. The pipes might bang a bit when you switch it back on as the water refills where the air was, but this should be just fine - then you run round closing all the taps again, after full flow is re-established.

*Important.* Switch off any water heating while you do this.

BTW, if you're absolutely certain that red/blue stopper needs to some out & you are not going to be re-using the tap, just bang it out with a small screwdriver wedged down one side & hammer.
…though I can't imagine why you'd need to take off any tap handles to get the tap out - one nut underneath, which you'll need a tap-spanner/basin wrench to get to, is all it should take.

They come in two types; "awkward to make it fit & get some leverage", or "slip & skin your knuckles". Unfortunately there's no third type that "just works";)

[image]  [image]

Well, there is a third type, but they're very awkward when you have tails out of the base of the tap. They used to be great on old fashioned taps with hard copper right to the back.

[image]

Comment: Hey Tetsujin, first of all, thanks for taking so much time to respond to my question in detail. It sounds like I need to contact my landlord and ask him where I can shut off the water. He actually built the house himself (it is quite small) so it might be a bit different than in standard houses. I am not able to see anything valve-like outside the house, I am a bit nervous it might not be possible to turn them off at all? Anyways will see.
Regarding the red/blue thing, you are right, it is not necessary for replacement. I mixed it up because I am actually hoping..(continues)

Comment: (continued)...that I can just replace the cartridge to stop the thing from dripping. For this purpose I would need to open it if I am not mistaken. In those Youtube videos it always looks super easy and they come off easily with a thin item, but mine seems a bit obnoxiously stuck somehow.

Comment: To stop a tap dripping you usually only need to change the washer - 10 cents/pence from a plumbing supplier. Take the old one with you for a perfect fit. And, yes, to get to that, you'll need to be able to get the top off the tap, but you don't need to get the tap off the sink. You do still need to switch the water off. As it's a rental, I'd say this is your landlord's responsibility, not yours - especially if you're struggling & have never done anything like this before.

Comment: BTW, you should **always** know where the water switches off to the whole house/flat/apartment, in case there's ever a leak. Your landlord is responsible for ensuring you have that information… & it's in their own interests in case there ever *is* a leak.

Comment: I just had my landlord coming over to show me where the switch is, and it turns out it is in the bathroom under the boiler...thank goodness not somewhere outside! and after explaining the situation with the faucet, he actually offered to call his plumber and have him fix it. He actually looked kind of scared when I mentioned I want to do it myself, I don't blame him LOL. I will watch the plumber closely though as dripping faucets drive me crazy, and this is one thing that I really want to learn to do myself. Thanks again for your input, really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: To the OP, since this is resolved, you could probably mark this answer as "accepted". This experience might serve as a reminder to you that you are a renter, and doing DIY without express permission from the landlord can expose you to significant liability. (What if your actions flooded the apartment? The landlord is going to come to you for redress.) And when the plumber is there, I suggest you ask if you can watch and learn. The majority of tradespeople are friendly and giving of their knowledge, but there's a non-zero chance that he doesn't want you looking over his shoulder.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I marked the answer as "accepted". this was my first post here in this forum, seems to be a great place for advice :)